# Copy only the New added lines of a file in another file every iteration

Tags: python

I have a file with mode append and with time the number of lines increases and i want to copy only the new lines that are added after every iteration of this file in other files. This code copy the new lines with the old lines:

```
def get_qatcher_log_file(source_file):
"""Get Qatcher Log File"""
lastLine = None
with open(source_file,'r') as f:
    file_name=source_file.rsplit('.')[0]
    filename=file_name +"_" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%Mm%S.%fs") + ".log"
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        lastLine = line
while True:    
    with open(source_file,'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    if lines[-1] != lastLine:
        data=lines[len(lastLine):]  
    else:
        if lines[-1] == lastLine: 
            data=lines 

        print("line",data)        
    with open(filename,"a") as f_destination:
            f_destination.writelines(data)
            f_destination.close()
    print("line",data)
    print("lastLine",lastLine)
    return filename
```

I have modified my code to this new code but it still copy all the file not only in the appended lines in the last of the file. Does anyone have an idea how i can copy only the new lines added in the end of the same file and thank you in advance.

Comment: First thing that caught my eye was `for i in len(var):` - since `len(var)` evaluates to an integer, it would effectively mean e.g. `for i in 5:`. And you can't iterate over a number! You probably wanted `for i in range(len(var)):` (you probably saw `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` at some point).

Comment: @alex, yes i have got this fail. the file i am working on is a log file that contains the traces after runing a test suite and i want to store the traces of every test case in a separated log file.

Comment: Doesn't your first version of the function only change the file name, but not the file itself?

Comment: @Arne, the first version of the code copy the lines of the file in other file with different name.

Comment: Can I move lines of a file with append mode to another file? PS: i can't remove the file

Comment: Yes, you can, by using `open(file_name +..., "a")` instead of `open(file_name +..., "w")`. That would open the file in append mode rather than write mode. But it seems that what you really want to do is to select certain lines from the source file and only copy those, right? So you could consider a loop that iterates over the list of new file names, and in each iteration you read only the appropriate lines from the source file and write those to the new file of the current name.

Comment: @Arne, thank you for the solution and yes  i need to copy only the last added lines in the new files every time there are added lines in the source file